# How to check if int variable has been set?

Tags: go

Lets say I have a variable `num`.

Before I can evaluate an `if` statement, I need to check if this variable has been set in the first place. Typically I would use either `-1`, `0` or `math.MaxInt32/math.MinInt32` but for this task I need to check if my program has set its value.

I tried `nums := nil` and in my `if` statement I had something like `if nums == nil || ...`.

But when creating the `nums` variable I was surprised to get the error `cannot convert nil to type int`. How I can achieve what I want to do?

To make it clear: This is a leetcode [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/third-maximum-number/description/) and don't have control of the inputs, they put all sorts of numbers inside include math.MaxInt32, math.MinInt32

Full code:

```
func thirdMax(nums []int) int {

    dict := make(map[int]int, 0)

    varmaxOne := math.MinInt32
    maxTwo := math.MinInt32
    maxThree := math.MinInt32


    for _, value := range nums {

        if value >= maxOne && dict[value] < 1 {

            maxThree = maxTwo
            maxTwo = maxOne
            maxOne = value

        }else if value >= maxTwo && dict[value] < 1{
            maxThree = maxTwo
            maxTwo = value
        } else if value >= maxThree && dict[value] < 1 {
            maxThree = value
        }

        dict[value] += 1
    }

    if maxThree == math.MinInt32 {
        return maxTwo
    }
    return maxThree

}

func max(a int, b int) int {
    if a > b {
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

Test

```
func TestThirdMax(t *testing.T) {
    //array := []int{2, 3, -1, -9, 11, 4, 3, 0, -100}
    //array := []int{2, 2, 3, 1}
    array := []int{1,2,-2147483648}
    //array := []int{3,2,1}
    result := thirdMax(array)

    if result != 2 {
        t.Errorf("Expected 2, but it was %d instead.", array)
    }
}
```

The code above use `math.MinInt32`, but fails with the input given. The idea was to have `nil` instead and put a check in the `if` statement, but fails as stated above.

Comment: What do you mean by "set"? A non-initialised variable will hold the zero value for its type.

Comment: an integer can only hold integer values. You need a different type if you want to check for other possible states, maybe `*int`?

Comment: interesting. so every type has its own "zero"? let me try that

Comment: Yes, every type has a [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value).

Comment: Yes, every type has a "zero value". For `int` the "zero value" is, unsurprisingly, `0`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the comments suggest, the Zero Value for all int types in Go is `0`.  If `0` is a possible value for a number, and you need to check if it has been assigned or not, then you will probably want to use a Struct type with some metadata attached, rather than the primitive type.

As usual for these sorts of questions, there are precedents for this in the standard library.

[Take a look at the database/sql package's Null types.](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64)  These types are also justified by implementing `Scanner`, but you can use the same idea any time you need to check whether a primitive value should truly be equal to Null, rather than it's zero value.

Comment: "then you will probably want to use a Struct type with some metadata attached, rather than the primitive type." --- seriously?? all that to just check if a variable has been assigned by the program??

Comment: @maxflow, if you apply some thinking to the situation, you'll come to an (obvious) conclusion that in order to track whether a variable has been assigned the compiler and/or the runtime must somehow keep tract of that fact. This basically means storing a flag value somewhere and then either set it each time its paired variable is set (so we have two memory stores, not one) or check whether it was already initialized (and so we have one memory read in addition to the store)…

Comment: …or do it in some even more costly way—like replacing an integer with an (otherwise "transparent") pointer to a heap-allocated integer value, and "chase" that pointer value on each access, so that on the first one (when that pointer is `nil`), actually allocate the value and write the pointer. Now please stop and give this a bit more thought. Basically, you'll ask for the compiler/runtime to pay this cost for all variables—even though for 99.9% of variables this is not needed…

Comment: …; now consider that in order to make accesses to such "guarded" variables transparent with regard to Go's memory model (say, an integer variable cannot be half-initialized), the compiler/runtime would need to use memory access synchronization for each access to such variable. This is an insane price to pay. Well, may be not that insane in a scripting language, where the program's speed is up front defined to suck, but not in Go, which is reasonably "close to the metal", and gives you enough control over memory layout of, and access to your data.

Answer (score 9):

As stated in the comments, you cannot check if an `int` has been set or not.

And using `math.MinInt32` as a signal value would fail if you get that in the input.

So if you want to implement it that way, the only option is to use pointers (`*int`).

With pointers, you are able to check if they were set because they start with a `nil` value as you expect.

However, the logic gets a bit more complex that you implemented as you need to work with pointers and references.

See below a possible implementation, trying to use the same logic you posted, only changing to use pointers.

Another option might be to just sort the array and work with the sorted elements to find the third one.

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/ro_NIrDEo_s

```
func thirdMax(nums []int) int {

    dict := make(map[int]int, 0)

    // these will start with "nil values"
    var maxOne *int
    var maxTwo *int
    var maxThree *int


    for _, value := range nums {

        if maxOne == nil || value >= *maxOne && dict[value] < 1 {

            maxThree = maxTwo
            maxTwo = maxOne
            maxOne = new(int)
            *maxOne = value

        }else if maxTwo == nil || value >= *maxTwo && dict[value] < 1{
            maxThree = maxTwo
            maxTwo = new(int)
            *maxTwo = value
        } else if maxThree == nil || value >= *maxThree && dict[value] < 1 {
            maxThree = new(int)
            *maxThree = value
        }

        dict[value] += 1
    }

    if maxOne == nil {
        panic("does not work with empty input array!")
    }
    if maxTwo == nil {
        return *maxOne
    }
    if maxThree == nil {
        return *maxTwo
    }
    return *maxThree

}
```